# punky window destroyed by woodpecker: minimally acceptable fix so it's watertight

Tags: repair, windows, waterproofing

This window is 30 years old. The wood siding abuts the window casing. There is no apron beneath the sill. On both sides of the window the casing wood is punky where it meets the sill, and on the right side the sill itself is punky. A woodpecker has pecked that corner down to nothing. You can see where the punkiness of the sill ends and the wood becomes firm again.

I don't want to replace this window for the time being (too many other projects with higher priority) but **I do want to make it water-tight and prevent further damage**. EDIT: Location is mid-atlantic, moderate rainfall.

If I cut out the front of the sill at the dotted yellow line, put some backer-rod in the void area and caulk it well, replace that cut-out sill piece, caulking the joints, repaint the sill, and then install new casing trim in a fat bead of caulk, painting all six sides of the casing trim first, do you think it should hold up, i.e. **be water-tight**, for a few years? If not, what additional would you suggest, or what other approach to repair?

The wood behind the casing is firm, not punky.  I could also paint behind the casing with waterproofing paint before installing new casing.  Removing the siding to install new flashing tape would be a major project.

[image]

Comment: the woodpecker may have detected insects in that area

Comment: @jsotola: a possibility, but I don't see anything inside suggesting insect damage.

Comment: Woodpeckers go after insects in wood, not the wood itself.  Insects caused the punky wood or pick punky wood to live in is a question.

Comment: The problem I see if you seal the rotting wood the reason the wood pecker was there will be multiplied

Comment: Sadly, "I need a temporary fix to last a couple of years, then I'll do it right" fixes tend to need to last more than a "couple" of years, because it tends to be forgotten about. (Guilty as charged.) Do a thorough investigation of what's behind the siding to make sure you don't have significant rot or bug infestation and your plan does sound reasonable for a couple of years...